# Creating files using variables in C

Tags: c, variables

I have a question here that I cant find anywhere. I have been looking for the longest and my professors are useless. I'm trying to create N amount of files inside a for loop in C. I've tried the following code...and clearly that doesn't work, how do i go about make these files inside a for loop?

```
int i;
int N = 10;
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    fopen(("file%d",i),"w");
}
```

Comment: proper grammer didnt allow me to put this portion up
essentially i want to make the files
file0, file1, file2....etc whatever N is.

Comment: Are you asking how to combine ints with strings or on how to create files? Not every C function lets you use formatted string syntax like printf, check out sprintf.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: `sprintf`  can be dangerous (and is becoming deprecated). Should use `snprintf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 int i;
 const int N = 10;
 for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    char nambuf[32];
    snprintf (nambuf, sizeof(nambuf), "file%d", i);
    FILE* f = fopen(nambuf, "w");
    if (!f) {perror(nambuf); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
    // print something in f, like
    fprintf (f, "this is %s\n", nambuf);
    fclose(f);
 }
```

Read documentation of [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html), [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [fclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) ...

`snprintf` is useful to fill a string buffer. `fopen` can take such a buffer. Errors could happen, so we test some of them (you should also test failure of `fprintf` & `fclose` but I am lazy for that) and use `perror` to report them.

Learn about [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) and [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: you are a genious!! it worked, thanks a lot. Seems like to do a simple task, takes much more lines to do in C.

Comment: Please take time to read more books about C. Study the source code of some existing free software....

Comment: Ive used all this stuff before, I just didnt think to put all of them together @gekannt and like i said, ive searched, but nothing came up like this anywhere

Comment: @StevenR: what source code of some free software in C have you looked into?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i just google what im looking for, its always something very simple (thats the worst part) but if i understand your question correctly, ive looked at a lot of source code, but Ive just been brain fried past couple days, doing things in C i dont even know, I always tend to ask the very simple questions that i get stuck on. and deal with the hard problems myself

Comment: *Studying the source code* of some C free software you like and know is *very instructive*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you, I'll definitely look into free software to study it.